# Quartz 2.1.x does not list all scheduled jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to display all scheduled jobs, even those that never started up to now (but which are scheduled).

This code only displays all scheduled jobs that have already started at least once:

```
// enumerate each job group
for(String group: sched.getJobGroupNames()) {
    // enumerate each job in group
    for(JobKey jobKey : sched.getJobKeys(groupEquals(group))) {
        System.out.println("Found job identified by: " + jobKey);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?
I'm using Java SE 8 and Quartz 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just found it out. In one section of the code I found out that one job was not scheduled, so the following line was missing:
`sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);`

So if you have the same issue, make sure that all jobs are scheduled properly.